# Accessing previously loaded data in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In the [Ember JS Application Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/router_primer/#toc_from-a-list-of-shoes-to-a-shoe), the author shows how to show a list of shoes and then eventually just show one shoe.

The problem, is in his example, he mimics a slow JSON request (using `setTimeout`) to get ALL shoes but then he just refers directly to the object literal to show one shoe.

My question: What is the appropriate approach to pull data using JSON once for a collection of items, then refer to the downloaded collection for other methods (i.e Show one shoe)

I don't need it to be persistent across sessions, just work until the user closes the browser/tab.

[The JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EasyCo/yZFXE/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, the `setTimeout` callback places the collection into `App.Shoe`, which is a global object.  You can access it any time after that using `App.Shoe._listOfShoes`.  So, if you just want to load the collection once and then re-use it, you could add confirm before making the request, whether the data has already been loaded.  That is, something like:

```
if (this._listOfShoes.length == 0) {
    // load the collection
}
return this._listOfShoes;
```